Android Studio "find usages" infinite loop
Since some time, maybe since last update or since switch to Kotlin 2.0 my Android Studio Ladybug | 2024.2.1 Patch 1 shows infinite loop when I click "Find usages" on any data class field. The search for class usage is working fine. If I use "command"+"click", it's the same. The search alternates between these two states:


Does anyone experience the same? Is it AS bug or something wrong in my project or settings?

Have you tried "Repair IDE" or "Invalidate Caches..." from the File menu?

I am also facing the same issue. Tried invalidate caches, repair IDE etc.

Yes, I tried that all as well. The issue is still there
